# Many blank slides added after title slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, blank-page, slideshow, frame

I just started a presentation and after the title slide, it seems over 100 ``blank" (as in it has the slide title and information at the bottom of the slides but that is it). Any idea why, or how to fix it? Only the last few slides do what I want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% For handout mode
%\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{default}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb, latexsym, epsfig, upgreek, mathtools,cjhebrew}
%\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb,, amscd, graphicx, pgf, tikz, MnSymbol, esint, nicefrac, units, stackengine, multicol, marvosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
%\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
%\usepackage{xypic}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd,MnSymbol}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}

%\usepackage{euler}
% For handout mode
%\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper,landscape, border shrink=5mm]

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\one}{1\hskip-3.5pt1}
\newcommand{\csm}{{c_{\text{SM}}}}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15} 
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85} 
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.80} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75} 

\begin{document}
\title[Spinning Tops]{Spinning Tops}
\author{Me}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1.0-> Preliminaries
\item<1.1-> Principal Axes \& Inertia Ellipsoid
\item<1.2-> Euler's Equations
\item<1.3-> Symmetric Top
\item<1.4-> Motion in the Ocean
\item<1.5-> Sleeping Top
\item<1.6-> Defying Gravity
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Preliminaries}
Asume Physics holds.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which documentclass DOES the posted code use? Looks like you commented it out?

Comment: @Matthew You should really clean up your preamble, there are a lot of packages and stuff which is not needed in a beamer document.

Comment: no document written since 1994 should be using `epsfig`, are you _really_ using it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `\item<1.6->` is wrong. More or less by coincidence, it does not throw an outright error, but it will cause all your extra slides.

The overlay argument is intended to specify on which overlays an item should be present. The numbers should be integers. For example if you want a bullet point to appear from the second overlay onwards, you should say `\item<2-> ...`

On the other hand, if you want to manually specify the enumeration number, which is shown on the slide, use `\item[1.3] ...`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item Preliminaries
\item<2-> Principal Axes \& Inertia Ellipsoid
\item[1.3] Euler's Equations
\item Symmetric Top
\item Motion in the Ocean
\item Sleeping Top
\item Defying Gravity
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```